# Find the general term of the sequence defined by $x_0 = 3, x_1 = 4$ and $x_{n+1} = x_{n-1}^2 - nx_n$

Tags: recurrence-relations

**Question:**
Find the general term of the sequence defined by $x_0 = 3, x_1 = 4$ and $x_{n+1} = x_{n-1}^2 - nx_n$.

**Attempt:**
If I'm not mistaken this does not match any linear homogeneous pattern, nor does it match linear nonhomogenous recurrence relation with constant coefficient. Out of desperation, I resort to finding a descent conjecture,

$$x_2 = 5\\x_3 = 6\\\vdots$$

I then conjectured,
$$x_n = n+3$$

I proved this using induction.

After solving this problem, lots of question arised,

1. Other than Linear Homogeneous Recurrence Relation, and Linear non Homogeneous relation with constant coefficients, what other **solvable** types of Linear Relations are out there.
2. Other than making conjecture like what I did above, can someone else recommend a technique of attacking the question above?

Comment: Do you mean solvable types of _nonlinear_ recurrence relations?

Comment: @Semiclassical yup.

Comment: Ok, your question doesn't reflect that right now. As for solving it, nonlinear cases are a lot harder than linear ones. Try different boundary conditions if you want to see why that might be so.

Comment: The point of the exercise is to make you realize that going out there and computing the first few terms of the sequence IS NOT an act of desperation, but is THE VERY FIRST THING anyone should do when dealing with unfamiliar things.

Comment: I can recommend only the following approach. Let you have a recurrence relation of the form $x_{n+1} = F(x_{n}, x_{n-1})$. Possible sequences generally form a two-parametric family and among them may exist both sequences described by an explicit formula, and irregular ones. If you conjecture that _some_ for them (but not all) have some predefined form, such as arithmetic progression, then combine a formula that relates 3 terms for this form with the recurrence formula into a system on $x_{n}$ and $x_{n-1}$. In a lucky case where such sequence exists, you’ll find it in solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an another approach solving the recurrrence relation 
\begin{align*}
x_0&=3\\
x_1&=4\tag{1}\\
x_{n+1}&=x_{n-1}^2-nx_n\qquad\qquad n\geq 2
\end{align*}
But first a few words to your classification of this recurrence relation. You're right when you're saying it's neither a *linear* nor  a *non-linear homogeneous recurrence relation with constant coefficient*. You could argue:

> *Type of recurrence relation:*

- Since the *constant term is 0* it's a *homogeneous* recurrence relation
- Since $x_{n-1}$ occurs squared it's a *non-linear* recurrence relation
- Since the coefficent of $x_{n}$ is $n$ it's a recurrence relation with *non-constant* coefficients
- Since $x_{n+1}$ is specified with the help of $x_n$ and $x_{n-1}$ there are *two degrees of freedom* and so it is a recurrence relation of *order 2*. We therefore need *two initial values* to fully specify the recurrence relation.

So, we can specify:

> The recurrence relation (1) is a *quadratic, homogeneous recurrence relation of order 2 with non-constant coefficients*.

Now an alternative approach in three steps.

> 1.) Ansatz: *$x_n$* is a polynomial $P$ in $n$

Since the initial values are *constants* and $x_{n+1}$ is defined as *square of a former term* and *$n$ times another former term* we could check if $x_n$ is a *polynomial in $n$*.

**Attention:** As *@ChristianBlatter* pointed out with a counter example in a comment below, it's *not always* the case that $x_n$ is a polynomial. It depends on the structure of the recurrence relation.

> 2.) The degree *deg P*

So, let's consider $x_n$ to be a polynomial $P(n)$ and try to determine the *degree* $d=\text{deg}P(n)$ of the polynomial $x_n$=$P(n)$. In order to do so, we rewrite the recurrence relation $(1)$ conveniently as
\begin{align*}
x_{n+1}+nx_n&=x_{n-1}^2\\
\text{or}\tag{2}\\
P(n+1)+nP(n)&=P^2(n-1)
\end{align*}
We observe
\begin{array}{rl}
\text{LHS has degree}&d+1\\
\text{RHS has degree}&2d
\end{array}
Since $d+1=2d$ we get $\text{deg}P=1$ and so we can choose the

> 3.) Ansatz: $x_n=P(n)$ with $\text{deg}P(n)=1$

\begin{align*}
x_n=an+b\qquad\qquad a,b\in\mathcal{R}
\end{align*}
With the help of the initial conditions $x_0=3$ and $x_1=4$ we find
\begin{align*}
x_0&=a\cdot0+b=3\\
x_1&=a\cdot1+b=4
\end{align*}
with the solution $a=1$ and $b=3$.

So, a closed form of the recurrence relation $(1)$ is

> \begin{align*}
> x_n=n+3\qquad\qquad n\geq 0
> \end{align*}